# Why aren't positional variables changed when one runs a command every time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am learning shell scripting and I have this situation.

We say that positional variables are environmental variables, but why they don't change every time a command is executed.

Take a look at this

```
set v1set v2set v3set v4set
old=$#

#Just a random command
ls -l

new=$#

echo $old $new
```

It outputs `4 4`. If environmental variables are global, why isn't it `4 1`, as I ran `ls -l` and it should have updated positional variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "positional variables are environmental variables"?

Comment: When you run a command like `ls -l`, whatever happens during the execution of that command (even if it involves invoke a sub-shell, which it doesn't in this case) will not affect the environment in the current shell.

Comment: @Nate, please don't point people at the ABS; irc.freenode.org#bash has enough trouble helping folks unlearn bad habits they picked up from it as it is. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is much more vigilantly maintained with respect to avoiding bad practices within demonstrative code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Fair enough: I just grabbed the first link I found on Google that discussed variable scoping in subshells. I've removed the link I posted so people will use yours instead.

Comment: The positional parameters *inside* the shell, as a result of arguments being passed to it (or via the use of the `set` builtin). They are not set *prior* to invoking an external process; `ls` and `-l` are both simply strings passed directly to one of the `exec*` system calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesant question - you got a good point.

For understanding it, you need understand what happens when you run any command, like `ls -l`. It has nothing with "variables are restored or similar"...

When you going to run any command,

1. the `bash` **FORKS** itself into to two identical copies
2. the one copy (called as child) will replace itself with the wanted command (e.g. with `ls -l`)
3. at this moment, the **child** process will get the correct count of positional variables `$#`
4. remerber - this happens for the child process, the second (*parent*) process know NOTHING about this
5. the parent simply waits until the child finishes (and of course, HIS `$#` is not changes, because for the parent nothing happens - only waits
6. when the child (`ls -l`) finishes, the parent contienue to run - and of course, **his** `$#` was no reason to change...

ps: the above is simplyfied. In fact, after the fork they are not fully *identical* but difer in one number - the parent gets the child's process number, the child this nuber has '0'

Answer (score 1):

> If environmental variables are global, why isn't it 4 1

I presume that you are asking why running the command `ls -l` does not change the positional parameters from four to one with the one being `-l`.

It does set them to `-l` for the program `ls`.  When the program `ls` queries its positional parameters, it is told that is has a single one consisting of `-l`.  Once `ls` terminates,  however, the positional parameters are returned to what they were before.

> If environmental variables are global,

Even for global environmental variables, changes to them in child process **never** appear to the parent process.  The communication of environmental variables is a one way street: from parent to child only.

For example:

```
$ cat test1.sh
echo "in $0, before, we have $# pos. params with values=$*"
bash test2.sh calling test2 from test1
echo "in $0, after , we have $# pos. params with values=$*"

$ cat test2.sh
echo "in $0, we have $# pos. params with values=$*"

$ bash test1.sh -l
in test1.sh, before, we have 1 pos. params with values=-l
in test2.sh, we have 4 pos. params with values=calling test2 from test1
in test1.sh, after , we have 1 pos. params with values=-l
```

And, another example, this one showing that a child's changes to an environment variable do not affect the parent:

```
$ cat test3.sh
export myvar=1
echo "in $0, before, myvar=$myvar"
bash test4.sh
echo "in $0, after,  myvar=$myvar"

$ cat test4.sh
export myvar=2
echo "in $0, myvar=$myvar"

$ bash test3.sh
in test3.sh, before, myvar=1
in test4.sh, myvar=2
in test3.sh, after,  myvar=1
```

Comment: Thanks, I had completely wrong understanding of env variables.

Comment: Using `"values=$*"` demonstratively isn't a best practice -- it conflates `"foo" "bar"` with  `"foo bar"`. `printf '%q ' "$@"` makes this distinction clear, as (to a lesser extent) does, say, `printf '<%s>' "$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `$#` applies to an interactive shell. It works fine in a script. Try this.

```
$ cat try.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $*
echo $#

$ ./try.sh one
one
1

$ ./try.sh one two
one two
2

$ ./try.sh one two three
one two three
3
```